# Set an array from array function in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

Is it possible to do something in C++ like:

```
uint8_t[] getSth() {
    uint8_t a[2] = {5, 2};
    return a;
}

uint8_t b[] = getSth();
```

Comment: Use a `std::array` instead?

Comment: @Ryan I'm new. How I can use it?

Comment: No, `return a` will lead to undefined behavior, and `uint8_t b[] = getSth()` won't even compile.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not like that: built-in arrays decay to pointers on return, so you would end up with multiple errors and a hanging pointer.

C++ offers several solutions, though:

1. If the size of `b`is known at compile time, use `std::array<uint8_t,2>` as your return type, and as the type of `b`.
2. If the size of `b` is not known at compile time (e.g. `getSth` is in a different library) use `std::vector<uint8_t>`
3. If the size of `b`is known at compile time, and you are restricted on the library functions that you are allowed to use, you can wrap your array in a `struct` or a class. This is the most indirect way of doing it, so I would prefer 1 or 2 instead.

```
std::array<uint8_t,2> getSth() {
    std::array<uint8_t,2> a = {5, 2};
    return a;
}

std::array<uint8_t,2> b = getSth();
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/BEBj4e)